# How to use matrix on NinePatchDrawable?

Tags: android, matrix, drawable

Now I have a problem with NinePatchDrawable.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(1, -1);
....
NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.bg_bubble);
Rect rect = new Rect((int) (curPointX + offsetX), (int) (curPointY + offsetY), (int) (curPointX + offsetX + bubbleImgWidth), (int) (curPointY + offsetY + bubbleImgHeight));
npd.setBounds(rect);
npd.draw(canvas);
```

the *R.miamap.bg_bubble* is a 9-Patch image, it should be added the *matrix* above.

Before, it isn't a 9-patch image, I used the code below

```
mBubbleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.bg_bubble);
...
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(1, -1);
...
Bitmap dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBubbleBitmap, 0, 0, mBubbleBitmap.getWidth(), mBubbleBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

But now, it is a 9-patch image, so I don't know how to do it. And I search the solution on Google, but with no result.

Comment: No, **you can't**. Because a 9 patch will loose its patching properties, when scaled or rotated or otherwise manipulated. Which actually makes sense, if you understand how a 9 patch works. You **could** work on everything BUT the 1px border, but it would be an overkill. Simply prepare 2 versions of your 9 patch (normal and rotated) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** do this .

Read this line

> The NinePatch class permits drawing a bitmap in nine or more sections.
>   Essentially, it allows the creation of custom graphics that will scale
>   the way that you define, when content added within the image exceeds
>   the normal bounds of the graphic.

Answer (score 0):

Oh,it seems like that I have done it in an opportunistic way. Exactly I want to rotate the 9-patch image, but the image also have different size because of the num of the content words. See the code below:

```
mBubbleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.bg_bubble);
...
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(1, -1);
// get the original bitmap with matrix
Bitmap dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBubbleBitmap, 0, 0, mBubbleBitmap.getWidth(), mBubbleBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
// translate it to a NinePatchDrawable drawable.
// Note: the third arg must be the original bitmap's chunk, because the dstBmp has no 9-patch chunk info.
NinePatchDrawable npd = new NinePatchDrawable(getResources(), dstBmp, mBubbleBitmap.getNinePatchChunk(), new Rect(), null);
// Draw it!
Rect rect = new Rect((int) (curPointX + offsetX), (int) (curPointY + offsetY), (int) (curPointX + offsetX + bubbleImgWidth), (int) (curPointY + offsetY + bubbleImgHeight));
npd.setBounds(rect);
npd.draw(canvas);
```

This is what I did. see the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn4I4.png)

What I say 'opportunistic' is that my 9-patch image's black points of left and top must be **IN THE CENTER** so that when I rotate it, the image will not be stretched in a wrong way !!!  hah...